# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send' discord bot

Tags: python

I need help getting my bot to work

```
# Import Discord Package
import discord

# Client (our bot)
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    # DO STUFF....
    general_channel = client.get_channel()

    await general_channel.send('yo')

# Run the client on the server
client.run('')
```

when I run it i get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send' in terminal and nothing shows up on discord if you could fix it that would be great

Answer (score 0):

The common reasons why get_ would return None are:
a) The channel ID is not found
b) The bot is not connected
c) get_ method is called before the bot is started.

In your case there are 2 obvious misses

1. get_channel method requires a parameter which is the channel ID.
   https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_channel
2. The bot is likely not loggedIn as client.run() also requires a token parameter. client.run('your_token')

Comment: i took out the server id and token so that way i didn't have to reset the bot token

Comment: Cool, The valid parameter for channel ID is an int. get_channel('444') is invalid while get_channel(444) is valid

Comment: let me show you a screen shot in a second post so then you can might under my error because i think its telling me to go one way and your telling me to go another

Comment: [enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUDpD.jpg
this is my error in terminal

Comment: When this "general_channel = client.get_channel()" was evaluated, the return value was None.  Hence, I wanted you to check if you had passed the right data type to the get channel function. It might be true that you passed the correct channel ID but not in the proper type expected by the function which is an INT